# Parsing the response Json string using groovy

Tags: json, parsing, groovy, response

4 for checking the status of the process using httpbuilder and getting the below response.

```
  {"result":[{"id":"167687","dapadmin":"false","status":"in progress","lastupdated":"2017-04-21 14:34:30.0","started":"2017-04-21 14:34:28.0","user":"sys","log":"Running a Stop action\n\nRunning command \n"}]}
```

Am unable to parse this response using     jsonSlurper.parseText()     giving error

When I use `

```
def json = JsonOutput.toJson(statusresponse)    
println JsonOutput.prettyPrint(json)
```

I could see it is printed as json object

```
{
    "result": [
        {
            "id": "167687",
            "dapadmin": "false",
            "status": "in progress",
            "lastupdated": "2017-04-21 14:34:30.0",
            "started": "2017-04-21 14:34:28.0",
            "user": "dapsystem",
            "log": "Running a Stop action\n\nRunning command \n"
        }
    ]
}
```

When i check the    getClass()    , it prints as java.lang.String.

I need to get the lastupdated and status , id values from this response. Please help me to find a solution for this.

### Many thanks

Hi Yanpei.

Thanks for the response.

I am using the below code as suggested by you.

```
    def statusresponse = http.putText(baseurl,path,query,headerMap, Method.GET)
             println("The status response value is"  )
             statusresponse.each{ k, v -> 
                 println "${k}:${v}" 
             }

             def json = JsonOutput.toJson(statusresponse)
              println "JSON Object List : " + json
              println "------------------"
                              println JsonOutput.prettyPrint(json)
                println "The result class  is "+json.getClass()
                println "The result status  is "+(json instanceof Map)


                //def entry = slurper.parseText(json)

                def slurper = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper()
                def entry = slurper.parseText(statusresponse)
                def lastupdated = entry.result.lastupdated
                checkStatus = entry.result.status
                def id = entry.result.id
```

Am getting the below error

```
       The result class  is class java.lang.String
        Caught: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: groovy.json.JsonSlurper.parseText() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.HashMap) values: [[result:[[id:170089, dapadmin:false, status:in progress, ...]]]]
        Possible solutions: parseText(java.lang.String), parse(java.io.Reader)
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: groovy.json.JsonSlurper.parseText() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.HashMap) values: [[result:[[id:170089, dapadmin:false, status:in progress, ...]]]]
        Possible solutions: parseText(java.lang.String), parse(java.io.Reader)
    at dap.Main.main(Main.groovy:171)
```

It works if i use the code as below

```
 def json = JsonOutput.toJson(statusresponse)
 def entry = slurper.parseText(json)
```

Am getting the results as below

```
The status of the action is :[in progress]
Last updated [2017-04-23 17:08:02.0]
the id is[170088]
```

First of all, am not sure why the code suggested is throwing this error 
Secondly, why i am getting the results for the working solution, within the brackets?

Comment: Why do you want to round-trip to JSON again after the builder did all that for you?

Comment: Thanks, am able to resolve the issue

Comment: Than you should explain how you did!

Answer (score 2):

```
def slurper = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper()
def entry = slurper.parseText('{"result":[{"id":"167687","dapadmin":"false","status":"in progress","lastupdated":"2017-04-21 14:34:30.0","started":"2017-04-21 14:34:28.0","user":"sys","log":"Running a Stop action\n\nRunning command \n"}]}')
def lastupdated = entry.result.lastupdated
def status = entry.result.status
def id = entry.result.id
```

Should work.  Can't see your error so I can't give better info.